# How do I use this block method?

Tags: objective-c, methods, block

I am a little bit confused about objective c programming with blocks.

for example Here is a method:

in the .h

```
- (void)downloadDataWithURLString:(NSString *)urlString
                completionHandler:(void(^) (NSArray * response, NSError *error))completionHandler;
```

in the .m:

```
- (void)downloadedDataURLString:(NSString *)urlString
                completionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *, NSError *))completionHandler {
// some things get done here. But what!?
}
```

My main questions is.... how do I implement this completion handler? What variables would be returned with the array and error? it is one area for the code but how do I tell it what to do when it is completed?

Comment: You cannot determine that from the block signature alone, certainly when no argument names are given.  You'll have to read the docs or some example code.  We cannot help.

Comment: i updated it with more code.

Comment: Well we could guess at what it does, but it would just be a guess.  Like any method, say, I provided you with, what it does and how you use it correctly is communicated through documentation and/or example.  There is more than one way to achieve the same thing.  You need to refer to the author of the code, or at least post a link for us to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to the caller to supply code to be run by the method (the body of the block).  It's up to the implementor to invoke that code.

To start with a simple example, say the caller just wanted you to form an array with the urlString and call back, then you would do this:

```
- (void)downloadedDataURLString:(NSString *)urlString
                completionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *, NSError *))completionHandler {

    NSArray *callBackWithThis = @[urlString, @"Look ma, no hands"];
    completionHandler(callBackWithThis, nil);
}
```

The caller would do this:

```
- (void)someMethodInTheSameClass {

    // make an array
    [self downloadedDataURLString:@"put me in an array"
                   completionHandler:^(NSArray *array, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"called back with %@", array);
    }];
 }
```

The caller will log a two item array with @"put me in an array" and  @"Look ma, no hands".  In a more realistic example, say somebody asked you to call them back when you're finished downloading something:

```
- (void)downloadedDataURLString:(NSString *)urlString
                completionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *, NSError *))completionHandler {
    // imagine your caller wants you to do a GET from a web api
    // stripped down, that would look like this

    // build a request
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // run it asynch
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {
            // imagine that the api answers a JSON array.  parse it
            NSError *parseError;
            id parse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&parseError];

            // here's the part you care about:  the completionHandler can be called like a function.  the code the caller supplies will be run
            if (!parseError) {
                completionHandler(parse, nil);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"json parse error, error is %@", parseError);
                completionHandler(nil, parseError);
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"error making request %@", error);
            completionHandler(nil, error);
        }
    }];

    // remember, this launches the request and returns right away
    // you are calling the block later, after the request has finished
}
```

Comment: I don't think so; the OP is asking how that method is invoked, not implemented.

Comment: @trojanfoe, question says, "how do I implement the completion handler".  Comment inside the method says "// what things get done here", and so on. But I see how it's confusing when talking about blocks.  Will edit.

Comment: this is what I was looking for. I was completely confused about how the block was useful until you showed this example thankyou!.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't be entirely sure without seeing any more details about the method, or its exact implementation I suspect this: this methods creates a new background thread, retrieves the data from the server and converts the JSON/XML to an `NSArray` `response`. If an error occurred, the `error` object contains a pointer to the `NSError`. After doing that, the completion handler is called on the main thread. The completion handler is the block in which you can specify which code should be executed after attempting to retrieve the data.
Here is some sample code on how to call this method to get you started:

```
[self downloadDataWithURLString:@"http://www.google.com"
              completionHandler:^(NSArray *response, NSError *error) {
                  if (! error) {
                      // Do something awesome with the 'response' array
                  } else {
                      NSLog(@"An error occured while downloading data: %@", error);
                  }

}];
```